# Not able to run as Exception in Application start method

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am using Netbeans IDE and created that file using Scene Builder 2.0. I created all the user interface using Scene Builder.

When I try to run the application this exception comes. I created JavaFX FXML application in Netbeans IDE and opened the fxml in scene builder and edited and after completion ran it in Netbeans but failed to get the desired screen.

**ERROR:**

```
Executing C:\J_Progs\Login\dist\run1115386562\Login.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/J_Progs/Login/dist/run1115386562/Login.jar!/login/Login.fxml:35

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at login.Login.start(Login.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.Label field login.LoginController.txtUser to javafx.scene.control.TextField
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application login.Login
```

**Login.fxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="650.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="login.LoginController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="lblMsg" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="39.0" text="WELCOME" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="40.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="271.0" layoutY="229.0" text="SIGN IN">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="130.0" layoutY="300.0" text="USERNAME">
         <font>
            <Font size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="129.0" layoutY="379.0" text="PASSWORD">
         <font>
            <Font size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="txtUser" layoutX="265.0" layoutY="298.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="235.0" promptText="Enter Username" />
      <Button layoutX="289.0" layoutY="481.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loginAction" opacity="0.84" style="-fx-background-color: #1e90ff;" text="SIGN IN" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <PasswordField fx:id="txtPass" layoutX="265.0" layoutY="377.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="235.0" promptText="Enter Password" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="18.0" arcWidth="18.0" fill="SILVER" height="174.0" layoutX="83.0" layoutY="264.0" opacity="0.41" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="506.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="12.0" arcWidth="12.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="35.0" layoutX="86.0" layoutY="229.0" opacity="0.67" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="500.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**LoginController.java**:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package login;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;



public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label lblMsg;
    @FXML
    private Label txtUser;
    @FXML
    private Label txtPass;


    @FXML
    private void loginAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if(txtUser.getText().equals("rs954") && txtPass.getText().equals("admin"))
        {
            lblMsg.setText("WELCOME");
        }    
        else
        {
            lblMsg.setText("WRONG CREDENTIALS");
        }    
        }    

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    } 
}
```

**Login.java**:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package login;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Login extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**NEW ERROR:**

```
Executing C:\J_Progs\Login\dist\run384200010\Login.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/J_Progs/Login/dist/run384200010/Login.jar!/login/Login.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at login.Login.start(Login.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at login.LoginController.initialize(LoginController.java:44)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more

Exception running application login.Login
```

**NEW EDIT IN LoginController.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package login;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label lblMsg = new Label();
    @FXML
    private TextField txtUser = new TextField ();
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPass = new TextField ();


    @FXML
    private void loginAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if(txtUser.getText().equals("rs95    4") && txtPass.getText().equals("admin"))
        {
            lblMsg.setText("WELCOME");
        }    
        else
        {
            lblMsg.setText("WRONG CREDENTIALS");
        }    
    }    

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    } 
}
```

Comment: Here is your problem `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.Label field login.LoginController.txtUser to javafx.scene.control.TextField`

Comment: You seriously wonder why an exception is thrown, if you write `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` (A cause that is very easily identifiable in the stack trace btw: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at login.LoginController.initialize(LoginController.java:44)`)???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

txuser in your fxml file is a textfield: `<TextField fx:id="txtUser"` and in your application a Label `private Label txtUser`. You should use the same widget in both.

Comment: so what should i add and remove in my code. Help would be really appreciated

Comment: @RockerRocky Look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/text-field.htm

Comment: I added this-:

    private Label lblMsg = new Label();
    private TextField txtUser = new TextField ();
    private TextField txtPass = new TextField ();

Still getting the same error

Comment: @RockerRocky same error for the same field?

Comment: can you tell what i have to write instead of the above label and textfield code i wrote.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at login.LoginController.initialize(LoginController.java:44)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
 ... 17 more

This came instead of Illegal Argument Exception @Jens

Comment: Add the compleate stacktrace to your question

Comment: @RockerRocky That is not the correct way to do it. You need to replace `@FXML private Label txtUser;` with `@FXML private TextField txtUser;` and `@FXML private Label txtPass;` with `@FXML private PasswordField txtPass;`